# Smarty: Returning data from database

Tags: php, database, smarty

Usually I retrieve and return data from a database like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo  $row['id'];
    echo  $row['name'];
}
```

But how to return the data using Smarty?
I think, I have to assign `$row`:

```
$smarty->assign('row', $row);
$smarty->display('search.tpl');
```

But I'm not sure how to actually display it. This doesn't work:

```
{foreach from=$row item=item}
     {$item}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `{$row.id}` and `{$row.name}` in your template (without foreach).

Upd. If you want to get all rows:

```
$rows = array();
while ($rows[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {}
$smarty->assign('rows', $rows);
```

In template:

```
{foreach from=$rows item=row}
     {$row.name}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need all of them, so there should be a loop.